# LibreOffice Draw: How can I change padding(s) around a shape

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-draw

Is there any way to change paddings (left or right) of a text inside a shape?

For example, in below screenshot, I have a circle shape with a character text inside it. How can I reduce the left padding of the text?

[image]

Please note that I know I can increase the size of the shape, or reduce the size of the font to have the text at the center. But with this question, I like to learn how to change padding inside a shape or margins around a text.

A screenshot would be great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Format -> Text Attributes. Change one (or all) of the items of "Spacing to Borders"

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help.